# While loop not running as expected

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Hey just for some background, I'm a novice enthusiast programmer. I've looked for help on my problem but couldn't find anything.
I'm making a text-based adventure recreationally and am wondering what I'm doing wrong. If the user entered a number that was not 1, 2, or 3, it should be rerunning the loop correct?

```
def print_inv():
    print("Your items: %s" % (inventory))


inventory = []
while weapon == "empty":
    weapon = input("Enter what weapon you would like to use:\n\nSword(1)\nStaff(2)\nBow(3)\n\n)
    if weapon == "1":
        inventory.append("Sword")
        print_inv()
    elif weapon == "2":
        inventory.append("Staff")
        print_inv()
    elif weapon == "3":
        inventory.append("Bow")
        print_inv()
    else:
        weapon == "empty"
```

Comment: Post your program as text.  I'm not going to give myself eyestrain trying to read that tiny screenshot.

Comment: in line 19, you're not assigning but comparing. Replace ``==`` with ``=``.

Comment: Don't get discouraged by the down-votes! They're related to way you formatted your post, edit it, and there will be many willing to help

Comment: Gentleman, I've done it. Too much free time. Brandon, if my answer solved your problem, and it did, please click on a gray tick below the answer score.

Comment: @f1sh problem is also there with the while loop condition because `weapon==empty` should be `weapon!=empty`  considering user inputs to keeps going

Comment: @PavneetSingh wrong. For the case of invalid input, the variable ``weapon`` is supposed to be ``"empty"``. That's why it's *not* supposed to be ``==`` in the loop condition. It only needs to be initialized as ``"empty"`` as well.

Comment: @f1sh i know it needs to be initialize but think in first iteration user entered  1 and it gets added to inventory but now weapon value is 1 which is false for (`weapon`=='empty')  so loop will stop right away but user wants to keep on adding inventory until user enter something else to quit

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign the value inside else case

```
weapon ='empty'
```

instead of comparison

```
weapon =='empty'
```

**Logic error in code**

Major problem is your loop won't work at all because at first time value of weapon should be set to `empty` due to condition `weapon==empty` if the value of `weapon` is already `empty` then again your loop will stop after first input set to `1` because

```
 # weapon =1 by user input loop will stop because 1 =='empty' is false

 while weapon == "empty":
```

so you need to use `!=` instead of `==` with `while`

Or you can use break , because simply you code does nothing useful instead of a comparison so you can stop the loop right away without assignment once value is `empty`

```
weapon ='zero'
while weapon != "4":
    weapon = input("Enter what weapon you would like to use:\n\nSword(1)\nStaff(2)\nBow(3)\nQuit(4)\n\n")
    if weapon == "1":
        inventory.append("Sword")
        print_inv()
    elif weapon == "2":
        inventory.append("Staff")
        print_inv()
    elif weapon == "3":
        inventory.append("Bow")
        print_inv()
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like the following:

```
while weapon == "empty":
    weapon = input(...)
    if weapon == "1":
        #something
    elif weapon == "2":
        #something
    else:
        weapon = "empty" #!!!!!!
```

`==` is used for comparing.
`=` is used for assigning.

Comment: this won't work dude , you missed the while condition flaw